# function doesn't work in PHP

Tags: arrays, string, response, jsondecoder

this a part of a class, trying to handle arrays and numbers in the response content but i encountered a problem:

```html
    public function is_jsonable($content){
        if(is_array($this->content) || is_numeric($this->content)){
            json_decode($this->content,true);
        }
        elseif (null !== $this->$content && !is_string($this->$content) && !is_numeric($this->$content)) {
            throw new Exception('Response Content is Invalid !');
        }
           return $this->content;
     } 

     /**
    * Set Response's content
    *
    * @param string
    *
    */
 function __construct($content = false, $httpCode = 200)
 {
        $this->httpCode = $this->httpStatuses[$httpCode];
  $this->header('content-type', 'text/html');
        $this->content = $content;
 }

  public function header($name, $value)
    {
        $this->headers[$name] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    
  /**
     * Returns the Response as a string
     *
     * @return string 
     * 
     */
   
    public function __toString()
    { 
      if(!headers_sent()){
          header("$this->httpProtocole 200 $this->httpCode");
          foreach ($this->headers as $name => $value) {
                   header($name.':'.$value,false);      
       }
    }
    return $this->content;
  }

};
```

and this is the index :

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/Core/Http/Response.php';
 
use \Core\Http\Response;

$test = new Response(200); 
echo $test ;
?>
```

the problem is that is_jsonable doesn't work, it works fine when i just instantiate the class with a string value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PVW7.jpg)

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what is the observable output / problem.  Error log? On screen error?

Comment: Recoverable fatal error: Method Core\Http\Response::__toString() must return a string value in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\public\index.php on line 9

Comment: You're putting Response into $test and it's failing a string conversion.

Comment: actually the test is for is_jsonable function and it doesn't work that's why it's failing a string conversion ...